# Simultaneous fragmentation and video encoding FFMPEG

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, mp4, video-encoding, fragmentation

Good day!
I encrypted and fragmented .mp4 video file, but after encryption, I can't decode it back. Could you tell me please what I'm doing wrong?
Command, which I use to encrypt:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\ffmpeg-3.2.2-win64-static\111.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -encryption_kid a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8 -g 52 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov C:\ffmpeg-3.2.2-win64-static\result.mp4
```

Command, which I use to decode:

```
ffmpeg -decryption_key 76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb -i C:\ffmpeg-3.2.2-win64-static\resultfragm.mp4 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 C:\ffmpeg-3.2.2-win64-static\resultlast.mp4
```

Result:

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ5ko.png)

Comment: 1) 3.2 branch is old. Update and try again before doing anything else. [Download ffmpeg from Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). "Nightly" version is recommended over release version.  2) Copy and paste the complete log text instead of making screenshots of the log text.

Comment: @llogan updated, but still have errors:


`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001e1f6869000] saio atom found without saiz
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001e1f6869000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720, 8658 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options`

Comment: And : 
`[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001e1f6869000] saio atom found without saiz
C:\ffmpeg-3.2.2-win64-static\result.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!`